# Using string as name for objects in Java

Tags: java, string, variables

Okay so I have the following piece of code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int i = 0;
while(i<1000) {
  String name = "event" + i;
  Event name = new Event(rnd.nextInt(100000)); //ERROR duplicate variable
  SimEngine.getScheduler().addEventToQueue(event);
  i++;
}
System.out.println(SimEngine.getScheduler().getQueue().iterator());
```

I know that declaring name twice makes no sense, but I hope you can see what I'm trying to do. Because I want Event objects with names event1, event2 ,event3 etc.

How can I get it to let me use the String name as the name of the Event object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Because I want Event objects with names event1, event2 ,event3 etc.

Objects don't (typically) have names. Variables have names. You really don't want to have variables with names `event1`, `event2` etc though.

In this case, you should basically use an array, if you really need to have access to the events by index.

```
Event[] events = new Event[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    events[i] = new Event(rnd.nextInt(100000));
    SimEngine.getScheduler().addEventToQueue(events[i]);
}
```

Of course, if you're not going to use the variable afterwards, it's pointless anyway, and you'd be just as well off with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    SimEngine.getScheduler().addEventToQueue(new Event(rnd.nextInt(100000));
}
```

If this particular kind of class *does* have a name associated with each instance, you'd need to pass that name into the constructor, I suspect.

Comment: Thank you very much! Both solutions are helpful, but as I'm not really going to be using each Event object afterwards anyway, I'll go with the second approach.

:)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot<sup>1</sup>, but you can use a [`Map<String,Event>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead, and put your variable names as the keys and the objects as the values.

To access the "variables" - you can use [`Map.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`Map.put()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29). Something along the lines of:

```
Map<String,Event> varaibles = new HashMap<String,Event>();
variables.put("event" + i, new Event(...)) //setting new "varaibles"
Event myEvent = variables.get(someString); //getting the objects assigned to a "variable"
```

---

(1) It could partially be done with [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). If you have the variables already (not declaring new ones) - you can access a variable by its name using the reflection API, but it is unadvised.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array, or a hash table.

```
Map<String, Event> m = new HashMap<String, Event>();
```

You cannot (at least not easily) set variable names during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to name each object in order to use a series of them, that's what data structures are for, ex array or map
so you can do something like

```
SimEngine.getScheduler().addEventToQueue(new Event(rnd.nextInt(100000)));
```

is that what you want?